# What was going on with Dennis in 'Charlie Work' (S10E04)?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, its-always-sunny-in-philadelphia

During the [*It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0472954/) episode "Charlie Work" (S10E04) *Charlie* has *Dennis* play the barkeeper during the health inspection. But all he ever gets out is a quite nervous *McConaughey*-style *"Alright, alright, alright"*. He seems to be in a complete tizzy and at the end when he calls back to the health inspector all he gets together after an awkward pause is another *"Alright alright, alright"*, all while sweating like hell.

So **what on earth was wrong with him?** Was he just overwhelmed by the "stage fright" of playing the barkeeper? Though, I'd not say this is a particularly difficult task for *Dennis*, especially since, like anyone else except *Charlie*, he didn't give a damn about the health inspection anyway. Did I miss anything else or was he really just totally nervous about his barkeeper role for whatever reason?

Comment: It seemed a little weird to me, too; I think he was either out of breath from sprinting around, or he had been taking drinks while pretending to tend bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fun fact: ***This episode was an homage to True Detective***, strange as it may sound.

**Background:** In early 2014, HBO released the first season of [True Detective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Detective_%28TV_series%29), which quickly earned rave reviews and plenty of fanfare. One of the more impressive feats by that first season's director, Cary Fukunaga, was an uninterrupted, action-filled 6-minute-long tracking shot in the end of episode 4 (you can see it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_HuFuKiq8U)). Inspired by this frantic single take, the IASIF gang decided to pay it homage. From a [Yahoo article](https://www.yahoo.com/tv/s/always-sunny-philadelphia-takes-true-detective-cue-082225439.html) about *Charlie Work*:

> The FXX sitcom, inspired by a long, unedited shot in the HBO series last year, fashioned its own for Wednesday's episode (10 p.m. EST).
>
> "True Detective" followed **Matthew McConaughey** in and out of frenzied danger for six seamless minutes. The FXX sitcom spends an uninterrupted seven-plus minutes on a scene that's equally manic but minus the gunplay: It involves a desperate bid to save Paddy's pub from flunking a health inspection.
>
> **Glenn Howerton, who plays Dennis and is an executive producer of the comedy about a group of loser pals, said they were "pretty inspired" by the bravado of "True Detective" and found an episode that's served by the approach.**

So in *Charlie Work* (which aired almost exactly a year after the TD episode it was inspired by), Dennis's impression is a nod at McConaughey's role on TD, and his gradual disintegration is funny in both the narrative and in a meta way: Dennis is clueless about being a bartender (a job usually manned by Dee), especially a good-natured one, and can only think of a single schtick - *but this is also the extent of Glenn's McConaughey impression, and he doesn't know what else to do.* [It's also worth noting that McConaughey's character on TD is often in shambles due to the effects of narcotic abuse and transforms from a young go-getter to an old drunk. *Sunny* might be deeper than we thought. ;)]

Comment: Amazing, I had no idea IASIP paid tribute to TD. Two awesome shows

Comment: There were a few below the surface level things in that episode. I remember the restaurant front was called Carmine's. Carmine is a colour of red synonymous with blood. It's is generally agreed that rarer steaks taste better, but Carmine's ended up serving a burned-black steak. I remember thinking something else was really clever, too, but can't remember what. Honestly, the fact that they were able to get that shot in one take with just a cameraman carrying the camera is in itself incredible. No programming or tracks, just a dude walking backward and everyone hitting their cues on time.